# JDBC/ODBC Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

I realise there are many question linked to this and I have read most (I won't say all because that would be a lie) of them but none seem to quite cover my problem.

I am currently maintaining a quite old application (Java 1.4 old) that uses odbc to (from what I know) access a local .mdb file.

To do so, the program seems to use a connection string like construct:

```
db.url = jdbc:odbc:Importer
```

When running it, I get the error set in the title of this question. Now, why don't most questions seem to apply to me:

- I work on a Windows XP SP3 32bit machine (that elimites all the questions where the solution is something with 64bit problems)
- I don't actually call the odbc by executing it, it just runs through the application

So, what else could the issue be? I know for sure that the exact same application runs normally on the customer's machine (I copied it to mine), so there has to be some issue with the configuration **outside** of the actual application.

What could it be? System requirements? Some registry entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.stoneedge.com/help/OM_DOC/tips_tricks/Creating_ODBC_Connection_in_Windows.html

- Click on the Start Menu.
- Select Control Panel.
- Select Administrative Tools and double click the Data Sources (ODBC) icon.
- Click on the System DSN tab.
- Click the Add button.
- Select Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb) from the drivers list and click the Finish button.
- Provide the mdb file... to database and provide name "Importer"

Comment: If you provide information from [an external source](http://www.stoneedge.com/help/OM_DOC/tips_tricks/Creating_ODBC_Connection_in_Windows.html), you should at **least** credit the original source.

Comment: Wow... I would have never even considered anything along the lines of that solution. Thank you so much.